# Importar ficheiros .csv para MySql WorkBench

Tags: mysql, script

Tenho um ficheiro .csv que na coluna A tenho:

> 1. Produto1
> 2. Produto2
> 3. ...

Na coluna B tenho:

> 1. 1
> 2. 2
> 3. ...

se quiser por exemplo meter na coluna A linha 1 escrito Prodúto1 como procedo no script? E qual o tipo de variável a definir na tabela?

Meu script:

```
use test; 

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'local' INTO TABLE tabela1 
CHARACTER SET utf8
fields terminated by ';' 
lines terminated by '\r'
;
```

P.S - mesmo sem a alteração do acento que quero fazer, o resultado da tabela da desordenado como faço para ordenar?

Comment: @PauloRoberto sabe esta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define uma tabela com uma estrutura que se adapte ao conteúdo do teu ficheiro. O Produto pode ser guardado numa coluna de tipo VARCHAR.

Fica aqui um exemplo que deves alterar de acordo com o teu caso especifico.

```
CREATE TABLE produtos (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Produto VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  Valor INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Depois para carregar os dados podes fazer o seguinte:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/produtos.csv'
INTO TABLE produtos
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@produto,valor)
SET produto = REPLACE(@produto, 'Produto1', 'Prodúto1');
```

A linha `IGNORE 1 ROWS` deve ser incluida se o teu ficheiro de input tem cabeçalho. Caso não tenha, remove essa instrução.

Ajusta a instrução `REPLACE` de acordo com as tuas necessidades.

Quanto à ordenação, ainda que não encontre a informação explicitamente na documentação, é uma aposta segura que os dados serão inseridos na tabela de forma sequencial, linha a linha.

No entanto, convém lembrar que não caso não apliques ORDER BY quando fazes um SELECT a uma tabela, não existem certezas em relação à ordem com que os registos irão ser devolvidos. Por vezes as linhas são alocadas numa determinada ordem e quando seleccionadas da tabela vêm numa ordem diferente.

Comment: esse SET não atualiza o acento. Existe mais alguma técnica sem ser o replace que se possa testar nesse scrip? exemplo tamanho de código etc..

Comment: Podes fazer um teste? Ao invés de fazer SET produto = REPLACE(@produto, 'Produto1', 'Prodúto1'); experimenta SET produto = REPLACE(@produto, 'Produto1', 'XXXXXXX1'); Depois indica qual foi o resultado

Comment: muda o produto1 para XXXXXX1 mas com o acento ele não faz nada

Comment: Isso significa que o SET está a funcionar. O problema está, muito provavelmente, na codificação de caracteres existente no Banco de Dados/Tabela. Tens que alterar a codificação da tua tabela: ALTER TABLE t1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8

Comment: @mas tenho que meter esse código em que parte?

Comment: Eu faria aquando da definição da tabela:
CREATE TABLE t1 (produto CHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8), por exemplo.